# How to handle unanswerable questions

Tags: discussion

Should old questions where the original asker is not responding to questions in the comments section be closed or deleted? If so, what's the appropriate response for the non-moderators, vote to close or raise a flag?

[Here's an example](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/leveling-concrete-floor). It's a good question, but without more details, or at least someone that knows the answer for all scenarios that wants to write a novel, it doesn't look like we're able to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's clearly no activity on the question and the poster hasn't been back then you can simply vote to close as too localised - unless you think an edit can pull the question into something that could be answerable.

However, given the traffic on the site this might not be enough so feel free to flag any you see that you that aren't salvageable and we'll take a look.

Comment: Will do, thanks Chris.